# How do I add extra text on to the end of a URL before it gets sent to webView?

Tags: url, ios5, rss, xcode4.2

Got an a question for you all here, what I trying to a do is I want to add `"?tmpl=component&print=0&layout=default&page="` and to the end of a articleURL, I've looked on google and came across something about `NSMutableString` but my articleURL is using a `NSString`.

How do I go about add this text on to my articleURL in real-time or should I do it before the  webView loads the page.

The webView is in a different view too.

Below is where I think my app is getting the URL for a RSS XML but I just can't figure out how to amend it to include the above for all the articles.

`code`

```
- (void)parseAtom:(GDataXMLElement *)rootElement entries:(NSMutableArray *)entries {

NSString *blogTitle = [rootElement valueForChild:@"title"];                    

NSArray *items = [rootElement elementsForName:@"entry"];
for (GDataXMLElement *item in items) {

    NSString *articleTitle = [item valueForChild:@"title"];
    NSString *articleDescription = [item valueForChild:@"description"];
    NSString *articleUrl = nil;
    NSArray *links = [item elementsForName:@"link"];        
    for(GDataXMLElement *link in links) {
        NSString *rel = [[link attributeForName:@"rel"] stringValue];
        NSString *type = [[link attributeForName:@"type"] stringValue]; 
        if ([rel compare:@"alternate"] == NSOrderedSame && 
            [type compare:@"text/html"] == NSOrderedSame) {
            articleUrl = [[link attributeForName:@"href"] stringValue];
        }
    }

    NSString *articleDateString = [item valueForChild:@"updated"];        
    NSDate *articleDate = [NSDate dateFromInternetDateTimeString:articleDateString formatHint:DateFormatHintRFC3339];

    RSSEntry *entry = [[[RSSEntry alloc] initWithBlogTitle:blogTitle 
                                              articleTitle:articleTitle
                                        articleDescription:articleDescription
                                                articleUrl:articleUrl
                                               articleDate:articleDate] autorelease];
    [entries addObject:entry];

}      

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also `NSMutableString` instead of `NSString`.

You can use like -

```
NSString *extraString = @"?tmpl=component&print=0&layout=default&page=";
[articleUrl stringByAppendingString:extraString];
```

Primary difference between using `NSMutableString` instead of `NSString` is -

If you use `NSString` `[NSString stringByAppendingString:]`, it will generates a new immutable NSString object, so cause memory leak. However, with `NSMutableString` it will append string in same object.

Comment: Ok, will give it a whirl. Thanks for answering.  :)